# How to change CSS of "html" selector programatically?

Tags: angular

I'm using Angular 6 and am in a situation where I need to be able to change "background-color" of "html" dynamically, without putting it into actual .css or .scss file.

I want to achieve the same effect as this snippet would achieve inside the global "styles.scss":

```
html {
    background-color: #000000;
}
```

Is there any way I could achieve that by writing TypeScript only? I have searched through CDK documentation of Angular but couldn't find anything suitable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your app doesn't need to render on the server, the easiest way would be to just grab it via regular DOM API and manipulate it.

```
document.body.parentElement.style.backgroundColor = 'black'
```

Otherwise, I'm not sure it's possible, since `html` is not part of your Angular application.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this code

```
document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].style.position = 'fixed';
```